# Why does this button handler return null on the second run?

Tags: java, nodes, binary-search-tree

This button handler's purpose is to search a binary tree for a location to a record inside a random access file. The method fillInfoField is there to populate the GUI with the returned data. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    private class HandlerSSN implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String ssnReqStr = tfReqSSN.getText();
        String num;
        int ssn;

        BalanceOnDemand.Node currNode = null;
        BalanceOnDemand myTree = new BalanceOnDemand();

        if (ssnReqStr.length() == 0) {
            tfMsg.setText("Lookup by Name (partial match allowed)");
            tfReqName.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else {
            try {
                raf.seek(0);
                myTree.root = (BalanceOnDemand.Node) ois.readObject();

                num = ssnReqStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                ssn = Integer.parseInt(num);
                currNode = myTree.find(ssn);
                System.out.println(currNode);
                if(currNode != null){
                    raf.seek(currNode.loc - REC_LEN);
                    fillInfoFields(readCurrRec());
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    tfMsg.setText("SSN \"" + tfReqSSN.getText() + "\" was not found");
                    return;
                }

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(currNode.id);
                tfMsg.setText("SSN \"" + tfReqSSN.getText()
                        + "\" was not found");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the find method if you would like to see it.

```
public Node find(int key)
{
Node current;
current = root;

while(current!=null && current.id!=key)
  {
    if(key<current.id){
      current = current.left;
    }else{
      current = current.right;
    }
  }
  return current;

}

  class Node implements Serializable
```

{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int    id;
public int    loc;
public Node   left;
public Node   right;

    public Node(int i,int i2)
    {
      id    = i;
      loc  = i2;
      left  = null;
      right = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show declarations of 'left' and 'right' objects of Node type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own. I needed to re-instantiate each of the input streams. Here is the code I added to the top of the button handler.

```
        try
        {
          fis = new FileInputStream("treeObject.dat");
          ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```